# How to Route from one Django app URL to another Django App URL

Tags: django, post, django-urls

I am using djoser for authorization. i want to logout using djoser - `/auth/logout/`   but it require `token` data using `POST` method.

my URL is,

```
 url(r'^logout/$', "{}/auth/logout/".format(API_URL), {'token':token}),
```

how do i bind post data into it? and how to call external API from urls.py along with POST data

**Note** : My djoser was in another django app. i need to do external API call for logout.

Comment: What happened to the defined `url ( logout ) ?` What is the actual result now?

Comment: i am having logout url in another app, i cant able to access that. logout api was in app1 loggedIn in app 2.

Comment: Okay you can't do like this and Django url can't post to external url with some data. All you have to do is some server processing. Can you elaborate what is `logout` in another app doing? Why you want two `logout` url ?

Comment: i am having server side calls in one app, client side including login was in another app. each time i will call app1 for login as well as api call

Comment: Okay do the same with logout as well...